# math operations between DataArrays using xarray module

Tags: python-xarray

I would like to perform math operations between several `DataArrays`. 
All my input arrays have same shape , e.g. (70, 560, 940), and I would like to have an output dataset with the same shape as input (70, 560, 940) .

If I perform an easy math operation,

```
DataArrayZ = DataArrayA + DataArrayB - DataArrayC + DataArrayD
```

Output `DataArrayZ` will have shape (70, 0, 1).

How can I do to avoid data dropping and have back the same shape input distentions?

Many thanks

**UPDATE**

Quoting the [documentation](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/computation.html#math-with-datasets)

> Although index coordinates are aligned, other coordinates are not, and if their values conflict, they will be dropped. This is necessary, for example, because indexing turns 1D coordinates into scalar coordinates

Maybe is what happening depending from that?

Comment: Mismatching coordinates sound like a very possible reason for this happening. Where do your DataArrays come from and what are their coordinates? In other words, can you post more code of what you're actually doing? If you know they mismatch but want to give new coordinates to the output, you could just take the `da.values` to get numpy arrays and perform the math, then create a new DataArray on the result with your new coordinates

Comment: Hi I am using data from https://cds.climate.copernicus.eu/cdsapp#!/dataset/insitu-gridded-observations-europe?tab=form. I did as you suggested but of course I lost coordinates. Could I be sure math operation is well performed?

Comment: If your resulting array has the right shape, then you can be pretty sure that it has worked. I'm still curious why it's dropping entire dimensions though. Can you update your question with some of the actual code you're working on where this problem occurs?